# How to Display Computers IPv4 Connections - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, networking

I am trying to only get my IPv4 addresses from this list. Is there a way display objects that return a value of IPv4 and not IPv6 from the AddressFamily property?

```
Get-NetIPAddress | Format-Table -Property IPAddress, InterfaceAlias, Type, AddressFamily
```

I want to keep this to PowerShell - I am aware there are other ways to find this information.

Comment: Add `-AddressFamily IPv4` to the `Get-NetIPAddress` cmdlet

Comment: Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress?view=win10-ps#parameters